# How long after I award a bounty must I wait before I can offer another bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have awarded a bounty that is supposed to default tomorrow, because I really want to offer one on a more pressing question. Now that the bounty is awarded, why can't I offer it on my other question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be something else.. when exactly did you ask the question you now want to offer bounty for?

It must be more than 48 hours in the past according to the bounty [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: Yes, thanks @Shadow. As I commented to Jeff above, my new bounty question is not yet 48 hours old, despite it seeming like it's been unanswered forever.

Comment: No problem.. I'm familiar with time flow of weekends as well.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the bounty rules? Read that bulleted list VERY VERY closely:

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I am very familiar with the bounty rules, but I had somehow mistaken my question to be two days old already,when I in fact only posted it yesterday morning. Weekends tend to to that to my sense of time.